# Sass compiler issues with ampersand and with update

Tags: css, ruby, terminal, sass

I'm trying to style a link and following BEM principles but I get an error from the sass compiler. here's the html

```
<a href="#" class="sg-link sg-link-icon">Link with icon</a>
```

and here is the sass stuff:

```
.sg-link {
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;

    &-icon {

        &:before {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
    }

    &:hover{
        color: $maggie;
    }
}
```

Now when sass watch compiles I get this error in the terminal:

```
error source/scss/atoms/_02-links.scss (Line 7: Invalid CSS after "    &": expected "{", was "-icon {"

"-icon" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.)
```

I've used this technique before and always worked so I thought that maybe the sass version has something to do with it. I'm using `Sass 3.2.13 (Media Mark)`. So I checked on sass website and latest version should be `Sass 3.4.13 (Selective Steve)` but when I try to update with `gem update sass` it says nothing to update. Tried with sudo too but no luck. Ideas?

**EDIT:** I've just checked the same code on Sassmeister and it works fine

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are correct about the Sass version. 3.2.x doesn't handle your snippet while using 3.4.x compiles it just fine. What are you using to compile your Sass? Are you using Sass from the command line or some build tool (e.g., Grunt, Gulp, etc.) to compile it automatically?

Comment: I'm running the watch with the terminal e.g. `sass --watch path/scss:path/css`

Comment: I see. Would you kindly paste the output of the `which sass` terminal command?

Comment: The error output is in the question, is that what you mean? if you need the output when I try to update here it is `ISVGRELT0001904:~ mliberato$ sudo gem update sass
Password:
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update`

Comment: I actually meant the output of running the following command at the terminal: `which sass`.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. here it is : `ISVGRELT0001904:~ mliberato$ which sass
/usr/bin/sass`

Comment: `ISVGRELT0001904:~ mliberato$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem`

Comment: Hm. Not sure what is causing the installation issues, but I've added my suggestion as an answer below.

Comment: think I know why : `ISVGRELT0001904:~ mliberato$ sudo gem install sass
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sass' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
` I'm on corporate network think I can't access the server.

Comment: Ah. Yep, that would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the Sass version. Using [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/), you can see that your snippet compiles at Sass v3.4.x, but not at 3.2.x (you can configure the Sass version in the control panel, under the cog icon menu).

As for why you are having trouble updating Sass in your environment is probably beyond the scope of this question, but it could be that your system's version of Ruby/gem is outdated. You might consider a Ruby version management tool like [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) for more fine-tuned control over which versions of gems are installed. I suspect that installing `rbenv` (for example), using it to install the latest version of Ruby, and then installing Sass with `gem` from there would solve your issue.

(Disclaimer: I'm not super experienced with Ruby, but I've found a setup like the one described above to work well for me.)

Comment: I've sorted the issue by downloading and installing manually the sass gem